# How to get tree of folders in CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line

In Windows CMD, I use `tree c: /f` to get a tree of all directories resided in C:. But now I only want to tree out the only sub-directory folders (not files). How to I exclude files in tree command?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Leave out the "/F" switch, since it's what causes Files to be included.

From `tree /?`:

```
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

Comment: beat me to it...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  Is there a way we can print this output to text or other file

Answer (score 4):

For Mac/Ubuntu you can do...

`tree -d` directories only.

You might have to install it beforehand.

// Mac
`brew install tree`

// Ubuntu
`sudo apt-get install tree`

Comment: Question is for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

to output to txt file use command: (you will find in on drive C, as specified below)

```
tree /a > "C:\_TREE-Output.txt"
```

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: It does provide more information though, there's the "store in file" with `>` part that the other answer doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The command `tree` works for showing all files and folders on **Windows**. The command `tree -d` does ***directories only*** on **Windows**. So yes, it does work.

Note: `tree -a` shows ALL FILES/DIRECTORIES, including hidden ones. You can combine them like this: `tree -a -d` in the terminal. This works on Git Bash and on Command Prompt but requires `tree.exe` placed in Git Bash's bin folder (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`). For more information on Tree's installation for Windows, see [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/531592/how-do-i-add-the-tree-command-to-git-bash-on-windows) on installation.

Good luck and happy programming.