# how do I use 'tree /F' command to git-bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I don't have enough reputation to comment [there](https://superuser.com/a/762629/250250), so I have to ask a new question here.

I can use `cmd //c tree` to use Windows' tree in git-bash for Windows. It only shows directory tree. If I want it also display files, how should I do it?

I tried `cmd //c tree /F`, but I get `Invalid drive specification` error.

Comment: Might I suggest: `cmd //c tree //F` or `cmd //c "tree /f"` (`cmd //c "tree //f"`)?

Comment: @TOOGAM They both work. Thank you! (but not the last one in parenthesis :) )

Comment: Awesome! Works -- the weird block characters I could do without. Is there any way to replace them with tabs or spaces instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one (or both) of these variations:

`cmd //c tree //F`

or
`cmd //c "tree /F"`