# Windows 10 Powershell tree command, how to show files

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, tree

How do I list folders *and files* using the PowerShell `tree` command? Is it possible to color format the output for distinct files and folders?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447014/use-powershell-to-generate-a-list-of-files-and-directories

Comment: See `tree /?`. `"/F   Display the names of the files in each folder."` As for colors, superuser isn't a script writing service. If you're stuck with a specific problem and post your code, people here would love to help you.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Simply use `tree /F` on any powershell instance to have the same behavior the normal `tree` on UNIX has.

The `tree` alone on Powershell shows only folders but not files in them.

Comment: how to filter it to only a specific folder?

Answer (score 9):

```
TREE Drive:\path /F
```

If command prompt or power shell are not recognizing 'tree', then:

Go to environment variables and change both the user variables and system variables "Path" to `C:\Windows\System32`
(Mine is `C:\Windows\System32` ,Find yours using `%systemroot%\System32`)

Then open a new power shell and give the above command.
EX:
[image]