# How do I get a listview to show up in Windows Explorer on Win 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, windows-explorer, directory-listing

I am trying to get a picture/screencap of all my folders, subfolders, and files in a directtory to paste into a Word file. I can't quite figure out a way to do this in Win10.

I want it to be something like:

```
Base Folder
│
├── Floder A (folder)
│   │
│   ├── Subfolder A (subfolder)
│       │
│       ├── readme.txt (readme)
│       │
│       ├── documents.docs (document)
│
├── Folder B(folder)
│   │
│   ├── test-script.sql (scripts)
```

Obviously something like this but nicer. I am open to a free component somewhere that I can adjust (like you can do with flowcharts, etc.). Is there a way to do this in Windows as I have tried the left pane of the Windows Explorer file structure?

Comment: Is Powershell also fine? https://superuser.com/questions/1270040/windows-10-powershell-tree-command-how-to-show-files

Comment: Try cmd, powershell or a third party tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a character-based folder/file tree to paste into a document using the following:

1. Open **Explorer** to the top-level folder
2. `<Shift>+<Right-click>` in the folder *background* and select `OPen PowerShell window here`
3. Type or copy/paste the follwoing command:

   - `tree /f | Out-String | Set-Clipboard`
4. Your file tree is now on the clipboard and can be pasted into any text document

Comment: whoa that's so much better than doing it manual